# document.getElementById() does not work inside function closure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use function closure in my javascript as follows:

In my html file:

```
<head>
    <script src="myscript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <section id="mysectionId"></section>
</body>
```

In myscript.js:

```
(function() {
    var id = document.getElementById('mysectionId');
    console.log(id);
}());
```

However, id seems to equal null. I'm not sure what I've done wrong - does function closure scope exclude globals like 'document'? If so, how come I can still use 'console.log()' inside the function closure?

Comment: Those two lines run right away, before `<section id="mysectionId"></section>` exists.

Comment: This is nothing to do with a closure. 1. You have an extra `)` in your code. 2. How are you executing this? Have a look at [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: @VLAZ: extra parenthesis fixed

Answer (score -2):

You're javascript is running before your html loads. Put your script tag after your html content at the very bottom of the body

```
<head>
    // put css here
</head>

<body>
    <section id="mysection"></section>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: or add `defer` on `<script>`